# What does this , operator do when you use it with = sign?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

i came across this completely randomly just curious because this this doesn't even look like a list .

[image]

Comment: In the future, please post all code as text. Images aren't helpful in the longterm.

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @Car are you using IPython?

Comment: @cricket_007 Ahh, missed that. My bad.

Comment: @Carcigenicate It works as the OP says in IPython.

Comment: It just works in IPython

Comment: I think this is a an `Ipython` magic.  But it's not something I use, so I'll have to look it up.

Comment: This appears to be an [IPython feature](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9698) related to autocall with the function omitted. See `%quickref`.

Answer (score 2):

This is [a weird side-effect](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9698) of the way the auto-quoting feature is implemented in IPython. In particular, every line entered at the IPython terminal is pattern-matched against [this regex pattern](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/splitinput.py#L44):

```
import re
line_split = re.compile("""
             ^(\s*)               # any leading space
             ([,;/%]|!!?|\?\??)?  # escape character or characters
             \s*(%{0,2}[\w\.\*]*)     # function/method, possibly with leading %
                                  # to correctly treat things like '?%magic'
             (.*?$|$)             # rest of line
             """, re.VERBOSE)
```

In the case of the input `', = what iss this'`, this results in [the following assignments](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/splitinput.py#L74):

```
pre, esc, ifun, the_rest = line_split.match(', = what iss this').groups()
print(repr(pre))
# ''

print(repr(esc))
# ','

print(repr(ifun))
# ''

print(repr(the_rest))
# '= what iss this'
```

Since `esc` is a comma, [the `AutoHandler` prefilter](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/prefilter.py#L628) reaches this `if-else` statement:

```
    if esc == ESC_QUOTE:
        # Auto-quote splitting on whitespace
        newcmd = '%s("%s")' % (ifun,'", "'.join(the_rest.split()) )
```

which modifies the command to become

```
In [19]: ifun=''

In [20]: the_rest='= what iss this'

In [21]: newcmd = '%s("%s")' % (ifun,'", "'.join(the_rest.split()) )

In [22]: newcmd
Out[22]: '("=", "what", "iss", "this")'
```

So in summary,

- the initial comma triggers IPython's auto-quoting feature.
- since no valid function name was found, the `ifun` is an empty string
- auto-quoting quotes the rest of the command string and forms

  ```
  '%s("%s")' % (ifun,'", "'.join(the_rest.split()) )
  ```

  as the new command. This "command" is then evaluated.

Hence, the result returned is the tuple `("=", "what", "iss", "this")`.

Answer (score 1):

Just using `?` in IPython to see **Introduction and overview of IPython's features.**

> 2. Auto-Quoting
>
>    You can force auto-quoting of a function's arguments by using ',' as
>       the first character of a line.  For example::
>
>    ```
>      In [1]: ,my_function /home/me   # becomes my_function("/home/me")
>    ```
>
>    If you use ';' instead, the whole argument is quoted as a single
>       string (while ',' splits on whitespace)::
>
>    ```
>      In [2]: ,my_function a b c   # becomes my_function("a","b","c")
>      In [3]: ;my_function a b c   # becomes my_function("a b c")
>    ```
>
>    Note that the ',' MUST be the first character on the line!  This
>       won't work::
>
>    ```
>      In [4]: x = ,my_function /home/me    # syntax error
>    ```

**EDIT:** Sorry for the `=` explanation. As @randomir said, the `=` op discusses is [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9698).

Comment: There's no function to cal in the question.

Comment: This does not explain behaviour with `=` at all. See the opened IPython [issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9698) posted in comments to the question.

Comment: Though it's part of the auto-quoting behavior.  It's trying to match the first element with a callable.  It's easy to get `not callable` or `not defined` errors.  Symbols/operators like `=`, `+`,`/` are falling between the cracks.